# iOS - iPad: Tabbarcontroller in landscape has incorrect layout

Tags: ios, ipad

I currently use a `UITabbarController` with a `UIToolbar` in the first tab. I have 4 `UIBarButtonItem`s, 1 on the left, 1 is flexible space, and 2 on the right.

This works well on an iPad in portrait, but when I'm in landscape, it doesn't. 
In landscape, it shows all bar button items, but only the left one is clickable. I'm using auto-layout and my constraints are set up to fill up all available width.

I did some debugging, and the 2 right items appear to be outside some touch-bounds.  I simply can't click on any items/buttons after the 768px mark, aka, the max width on portrait.

For some reason, the right 2 items will start working after I switch to another tab, and return to the first one.

I came up with a hacky solution:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex + 1;
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex - 1;
```

This works and will allow the user to actually press both buttons.

I don't like it, and it the UI glitches for a split second which will annoy the user. Is there a proper way of fixing this?